# A colleague has found that all the Google Scholar citations for a book of hers are erroneously attached to a book chapter she co-authored

Tags: citations, google-scholar

My colleague has written several editions of a book which we know is very highly cited. However, the book does not appear on her Google Scholar profile - instead all the citations for it have been added to a separate book chapter (with a similar name) that she has co-authored. These do not appear as 'merged', with the asterix next to the citation count, so she can't just click on that and unmerge them. It seems that GS is simply treating all editions of her book as 'versions' of the book chapter. What, if anything, can she do to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague can visit her Google Scholar profile

- click on the book edition(s)
- edit the entry (with the appropriate bibliography metrics within the limitations of GS)

  - -- keep as as (the edit)
  - -- remove the book edition
  - -- unmerge the edit and keep as a separate entry on Google Scholar

[Edit] *just in case, might be helpful for your colleague to maintain an [ORCID](http://orcid.org/about/what-is-orcid) profile which might also track variations of her name.*